# Wicket unexpected session id

Tags: java, session, jetty, wicket

I'm working on a webapplication using Wicket, which is running on a Jetty server.

In specific cases, a user of the application spontaneously loses his session and cannot login again until he closes his browser. (I've excluded session time-out and deliberate logout)

What is the best way to log session invalidation and trace the cause of this problem?

Comment: Have you excluded the possibility that you (or someone else) restarted the server?

Comment: yes, it happened over a period of multiple weeks, on random times and pages in the application. not related to a server restart

Comment: Could have simply been a Session timeout too.

Comment: Just curious; Is this happening on any specific browser (version), or any browser?

Comment: it's happening in any browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Jetty side, you can setup a servlet [`javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to log the various create/destroy events.

Create your own class for this, and add it to your `WEB-INF/web.xml`

```xml
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>MySessionListener</listener-class> 
    </listener>
```

Comment: Or you can use the `@WebListener` annotation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html and implement the `HttpSessionListener` interface.

Comment: I've tried this method, and it helps somewhat to get debugging info on session invalidation and creation. It does not help me with tracing the problem here, because it gives info at a point too late in the process.
 I'm searching for the point an incoming jsessionid is checked for existence in some kind of 'internal session id table'. If the session id is not recognized, it should warn me in the log. (existing cookie, wrong id)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a subclass of `WebSession` and override the `invalidate()` method to print out the StackTrace before invalidation.

That will help to determine if the invalidation of the Session happens because of something in `Wicket` or something outside of `Wicket`